# Custom-fit exponentials for linear multistep methods for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, least-squares

Coefficients for
[Linear multistep methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method)
for ordinary differential equations $y' = f(y)$
can be found by making an approximation like
    $\qquad y_{t+1} \approx y_t + \sum a_i y'_{t-i} $
good for polynomials ${ 1,\ t,\ t^2 ... }$ .

Why polynomials -- how about fitting $e^{\ z_i t}$ for a few problem-specific $z_i$ ?
(If $z_i$ is complex, fit a sin-cos pair, to keep everything real.)
Least-squares can easily fit polynomial + exponential terms,
and is robust and flexible -- can fit more terms, or down-weight noisier terms.
Exponentials $e^{\ z_i t}$ should be good for nearly linear $y' \approx z_i y$ .
My questions:

- Do such custom-fit-exponential methods work ? Are they used in practice ? Examples would be welcome.
- Given a trajectory $y(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a particular ODE,
  how can one fit a matrix $Z: y(t) \approx e^{Z t} y_0$ ?

Added: the question is not how to derive coefficients that fit exponentials
(least squares is one way to do that),
but whether the flow
$\qquad$ specific $f(y), y(t) \to $ fit $e^{\ Z t} \to$ coefficients $\to$ custom-fit solver
is much better than than just using off-the-shelf coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. However, what you want is to have in
$$
e^h\approx 1+h\sum_{k=0}^s a_ke^{-kh}
$$
an error $O(h^{p+1})$ of maximal order. Using $z=1-e^{-h}$ this leads to the identity
$$
z-(1-z)\ln(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^s a_k(1-z)^k=O(z^{p+1})
$$
and since $\ln(1-z)=O(z)$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^s a_k(1-z)^k=\frac{z}{(1-z)\ln(1-z)}+O(z^p)
$$
which can be evaluated in truncated Taylor series arithmetics.